# Filtering whole words with delimiter

Tags: java, regex, filter, delimiter

I have a delimiter in place that filters out symbols and numbers. My program is reading in a file and I would like to exclude some words from it but not all words. This might sound confusing but for example. If the first line in my file has the word `light` and the second line has the word `lightning`, is it possible to somehow filter out just `light` but keep `lightning`?

This is the code and delimiters I have put in place.

```
String delimiters = " ,*.-?|\t\r\n^;{}()[]+=<>/1234567890_";
ASCIIDataFile file = new ASCIIDataFile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any split or replace operation with the delimiter ?
You can use : the regex - "\blight\b" on the split/replace operation and it will match with "light" and not "lightning".

You can verify/test this out @ [JavaScript RegExp Example](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pattern matching in java

```
Set<String> Word = new TreeSet<String>(); 
while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^YourString");
                            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                            while(matcher.find()) {
                                Word.add(line);
                            }
                        }
```